# Getting TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python

Code:

```
x = np.linspace (0.0, 23.0, 22.0)
y1 = "time_dostavka"
y2 = "temp"
fig, df = pl.subplots()
df.pl(x, y1, label="time_dostavka")
df.pl(x, y2, label="temp")
df.set_xlabel("watch")
df.set_ylabel("temp")
df.legend()
df.pl(x=np.linspace(),y1 ="time_dostavka", y2= "temp")
pl.show()
```

Comment: use `x = np.linspace(0, 23, 22)`

Comment: I have a mistake - TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Why don't you look at the [linspace documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace):  third param - num - number of samples to generate - must be an int

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
x = np.linspace (0.0, 23.0, 22.0)
```

Must be

```
x = np.linspace (0.0, 23.0, 22)
```

---

`22.0` is a float. It must be an int. Which is `22`